# Hide algorithm, iterations, salt in django password field

Tags: django

In django user table password are encrypted automatically with a secure algorithm (pbkdf2_sha256) with salt and iterations. But what I don't understand is why the django password field shows the algorithm, iterations and salt in this format:
`<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>`

I thought those information are secret and I want to show only the hash.

Comment: Because you can use different algorithms, iterations and salt. Without specifying this, Django can not perform the same on a password to see if the hash matches.

Comment: But is showing the salt and iterations secure and safe ?

Comment: normally you should never expose anything of a password field. But it makes the search spaces bigger if we work with salt (especially if each record has a different salt).

Comment: But a hacker can decrypt the password using those information.

Comment: no, typically a hash function is seen as a *one-way* function: it means that calculating the hash is (very) fast, whereas finding an item *x* for which *f(x)* is a given hash can only be done through exhaustive search.

Comment: the idea of a good hashing function is thus that even with full knowledge of the salt, etc. you can not effectively determine the real password. Take a look at AES encryption for example: even if you know that the communication happens over an AES encryption, as long as you do not have the private key, you can not *efficiently* know what the actors are talking about, or at least at the time of writing there is no publication that claims it can "hack" AES encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought those information are secret and I want to show only the hash.

It is secret in the sense that you should not expose this. But since a password can be hashed with *different* hashing algorithms that take a *different* number of iterations, and a *different* salt, you can not match the hashing with the password.

Indeed, when Django wants to check if the password matches, it will need to perform the exact *same* hashing (so the same algorithm, number of iterations and salt) to check if the two hashes are the same. Django thus needs this info to check the hash.

Note that here the salt is each time different, so by adding salt, the "*search space*" grows exponentially, and thus [rainbow table attacks [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) are less successful. Furthermore as long as hashing is cheap in one way, but can only be determined through exhaustive search in the different direction, then hashing is a security measurement.

If one would not store the algorithm, number of iterations and salt *per* user, but simply store these things in a file, then we use the same algorithm with the same number of iterations and the same salt each time. In that case, a rainbow table attack can be more effective. By specifying random salt *per* record and with a , we let the "search space" grow exponentially with the length of the salt.

If the hashing algorithm is a [*one way function* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), then providing the parameters like the salt, algorithm and number of iterations will not suffice to calculate the function in reverse without exponential search, which is costly and easily scales beyond feasible with the current technology level.